# Drag and drop table jquery plugin and ajax issue

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery

i am using drag and drop table jquery plugin in my project. but i don't know how i can connect the new order of table with ajax to backend php script.
it author of plugin has said the serialise() method should be used but i don't know how.

thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Some existing js and html code would help, but roughly you want something like this:

```
$.ajax({url: "your_url", data: $("#yourForm").serialize(), type: "POST"});
```

... where "yourForm" is the id of your form.

Comment: thanks,but as i know there is a limitation for number of characters in uri,so the string is produced by serialize method will be cut for long data.is it true?

Comment: @hd you're right in that it's not good practice to put extremely long data in the query string. When submitting data to be saved on the server, it is best to use POST anyway, which does not rely on, and thus is not limited by, the uri. I'll update my answer for POST.